# Directory write permission to local service during installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, file-permissions

I have a Windows Service(Local Service), a Windows form application and asp.net web service application as a part of same installation.

I want to save the logs of all 3 to the same directory (CommonAppDataFolder) but they don't have sufficient privileges to write to the directory.

I have specified AdminUser launch condition and edited .vdproj file to elevate privileges. but still did not work.

Is it possible to give provide write permissions to a folder under CommonAppDataFolder during installation setup?

I am using visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting write permissions for Everyone for that folder. You can use the LockPermissions table in MSI or run XCACLS.exe as a custom action: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754